# Load local KML file using ArcGIS api for android

Tags: android, kml, arcgis

I am using ArcGIS api for android and I want to load a local KML file.I use the following code sample

```
String url = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "\\Android\\data\\com.tehranuni.hazard.hazard\\us_states.kml";

    SpatialReference sr = SpatialReference.create(102100);
    System.out.println("kmlurl: " + url);

    KMLLayer kmlLayer = new KMLLayer(url, sr); 
    mMapView.addLayer(kmlLayer);
```

This code gives me following error

```
KML layer fails to initializecom.esri.core.io.EsriServiceException: File not found. Wrong url or out of memory.
```

But when I use an online version of the same KML it works fine.I mean when I change url to a url it works great

I know the error means that the kml does not exist in the location but I have copied it already
Can you help me find a good solution to it?thanks you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make these changes:

- Use [`KmlLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/ogc/kml/KmlLayer.html) instead of [`KMLLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/ogc/KMLLayer.html). `KMLLayer` supports only KML URLs on the public Internet, and it is deprecated. It will not work for a local KML file. `KmlLayer` supports both local KML files and KML URLs.
- Be sure you've given your app permission to access local files:

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

  or

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
- Use forward slashes, not backslashes. Backslashes are not used as path separators except on Windows.
- Use the `File` class to construct your file path, just in case `getExternalStorageDirectory()` includes a slash at the end on some devices.

Here's your new code:

```
File kmlFile = new File(
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
    "Android/data/com.tehranuni.hazard.hazard/us_states.kml");
//Here you could check kmlFile.exists() to see if the app can actually see the file.
//If it's false, maybe you didn't grant permissions, or maybe the file path is wrong.

KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(kmlFile.getAbsolutePath()); 
mMapView.addLayer(kmlLayer);
```

Comment: Woww..Thank you so much,I changed to KmlLayer and it works..Thank you so much

Comment: Hello,Can you please take a look at this question ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784397/how-to-makeidentify-task-in-arcgis-api-for-android-work-with-a-standard-wms